# Using telnet connection, sending commands and receiving data using putty, plink or hyperterminal

Tags: telnet, putty, plink

I need to create a batch file and script that will issue two commands to a datalogger and log the requested data to a file.
I have a profile of the connection created in putty and can create a batch file that will open up the session and connect in both plink and putty.  From there I can manually paste the command into plink and receive data.

The command looks like this "#12345678D@5,19[ETX]" basically requesting the last 5 sets of unmarked data.
The next command is even simpler... "#12345678OK,56[ETX]" acknowledging the data and marking them in the datalogger as sent.

One complication is that the connection takes about 5 to 10 seconds to take establish so there is a need for a wait or sleep before the first command.

In the end this batch file and script need to run once an hour.  I am relatively inexperienced with code and languages, and greatly appreciate any help or direction.

Answer (score 0):

Neither putty nor plink or hyperterminal are the tool of choice: Use `netcat` (or `nc`), which is made especially for that purpouse - it provides the plumbing between stdin/stdout and network sockets.